# Efficient approach to find co-prime subarrays

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Given an array, is it possible to find the number of co-prime sub arrays of the array in better than O(N²) time? Co-prime arrays are defined as a contiguous subset of an array such that GCD of all elements is 1.

Comment: I'm assuming that finding the GCD of two numbers is considered constant time in this case.

Comment: @biziclop...yes

Answer (score 1):

Consider adding one element to the end of the array. Now find the rightmost position, if any, such that the sub-array from that position to the element you have just added is co-prime. Since it is rightmost, no shorter array ending with the element added is co-prime. Since it is co-prime, every array that starts to its left and ends with the new element is co-prime. So you have worked out the number of co-prime sub-arrays that end with the new element. If you can find the rightmost position efficiently - say in O(log n) instead of O(n) - then you can count the number of co-prime sub-arrays in O(n log n) by extending the array one element at a time.

To make it possible to find rightmost positions, think of the full array as the leaves of a complete binary tree, padded out to make its a length a power of two. At each node put the GCD of all of the elements below that node - you can do this from the bottom up in time O(n). Every contiguous interval within the array can be covered by a collection of nodes of size O(log n) such that the interval consists of the leaves underneath the nodes, so you can compute the GCD of the interval is time O(log n).

To find the rightmost position forming a co-prime subarray with your current element, start with the current element and check to see if it is 1. If it is, you are finished. If not, look at the element to its left, take a GCD with that, and push the result on a stack. If the result is 1, you are finished, if not, do the same, but look to see if there is a sub-tree of 2 elements you can use to add 2 elements at once. At each of the succeeding steps you double the size of the sub-tree you are trying to find. You won't always find a convenient sub-tree of the size you want, but because every interval can be covered by O(log n) subtrees you should get lucky often enough to go through this step in time O(log n).

Now you have either found that whole array to the current element is not co-prime or you have found a section that is co-prime, but may go further to the left than it needs. The value at the top of the stack was computed by taking the GCD of the value just below it on the stack and the GCD at the top of a sub-tree. Pop it off the stack and take the GCD of the value just below it and the right half of the sub-tree. If you are still co-prime then you didn't need the left half of the sub-tree. If not, then you needed it, but perhaps not all of it. In either case you can continue down to find the rightmost match in time O(log n).

So I think you can find the rightmost position forming a co-prime subarray with the current element in time O(log n) (admittedly with some very fiddly programming) so you can count the number of coprime sub-arrays in time O(n log n)

Two examples:

List 1, 3, 5, 7. The next level is 1, 1 and the root is 1. If the current element is 13 then I check against 7 and find that gcd(7, 13) = 1. Therefore I immediately know that GCD(5, 7, 13) = GCD(3, 5, 7, 13) = GCD(1, 3, 4, 7, 13) = 1.

List 2, 4, 8, 16. The next level is 2, 8 and the root is 2. If the current numbers is 32 then I check against 16 and find that gcd(16, 32) = 16 != 1 so then I check against 8 and find that GCD(8, 32) = 8 and then I check against 2 and find that GCD(2, 32) = 2 so there is no interval in the extended array which has GCD = 1.

Comment: Could you please give an example showing how the tree can help avoid comparing an added element to all previous elements, given a list that's all coprime? I don't see how that's possible.

Comment: I have added examples. I think it possible that we don't agree on what a coprime list is. I take it to mean that the greatest number which divides all elements of the list is 1.

Comment: Thanks! But sorry, I still don't get it. If you know that [a,b] are coprime, how can you know that [a,b,c] are coprime without finding the GCD of (c,b) and the GCD of (c,a)?

Comment: If you say that a coprime array is one in which the largest number dividing ALL elements of the array is 1, then adding any number to the array preserves this property. By this definition {6, 10, 15} is a coprime array because gcd(gcd(6, 10), 15) = gcd(2, 15) = 1. Therefore so is {6, 10, 15, 900} because although 15 divides 900, there is no number greater than 1 which divides 6, and 10, 15 and, and 900.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I misunderstood the definition. Thanks!